# SQL select by 3 tables

Tags: mysql

Hi I want to select `'charge'` from table imputations which have `'userId', actionId , date, charge` columns but I want to select with conditions:

1. `from jirachanges where ChangeTo='Resolved' and  changeDate >='2016-12-01' and changeDate <='2016-12-31'`
2. `FROM tasks where  type = 1`
3. `FROM users where groupmember='TMA' and active=1`
4. `from actions`  ( to find jiraTaskId in imputations table )
   and `where` :

   - `imputations.id=actions.actionId`
   - `tasks.id=actions.taskId`
   - `imputations.userId=tasks.assigneeUserId`

Comment: show your table please

Comment: I suspect you will continue to gather down votes unless you improve your question by providing your table definitions and the relationships between them.

Answer (score 0):

would be great if you could youse the code function to outline your MySQL-Code ;-)

If I get this right it looks like you need to [`JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) your tables.

You do that by connecting somehow the primary keys of each table:

```
SELECT imputations.charge ....
FROM imputations
INNER JOIN jirachanges ON [imputations.primaryKey] = [jirachanges.primaryKey]
WHERE jirachanges.ChangeTo = 'Resolved' AND jirachanges.changeDate >= '2016-12-01' ...
```

Note that you can do mulitple `INNER JOIN`s, they have to be above the `WHERE` clause.

Hope this is what you're searching for